# IntelliJ Idea mapstruct java: Internal error in the mapping processor:com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$BadClassFile: bad class file

Tags: intellij-idea, mapstruct

Recently I started getting **bad class file** during build in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 and MapStruct version 1.4.2.Final. Maven build is running fine. Does anyone have a clue? Thanks a lot!!

Intellij compiler logs:

```
DEBUG - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - java:ERROR:Internal error in the mapping processor: com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$BadClassFile: bad class file:    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.  
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.badClassFile(ClassReader.java:357)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readEnclosingMethodAttr(ClassReader.java:1276)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$12.read(ClassReader.java:1130) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readAttrs(ClassReader.java:1381)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassAttrs(ClassReader.java:1396) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:2226) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassFile(ClassReader.java:2324)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:2511)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:2442) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.access$000(ClassReader.java:76) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$1.complete(ClassReader.java:240) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:574)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1037) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.flags(Symbol.java:973)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol.getEnclosedElements(Symbol.java:734)
  at javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6.visitPackage(ElementScanner6.java:167) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$PackageSymbol.accept(Symbol.java:901)      
  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacRoundEnvironment$AnnotationSetScanner.scan(JavacRoundEnvironment.java:158)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacRoundEnvironment$AnnotationSetScanner.scan(JavacRoundEnvironment.java:127) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacRoundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(JavacRoundEnvironment.java:121) 
  at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.getMappers(MappingProcessor.java:235)
  at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:165) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:802)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:713)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1043) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1184)
  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170) 
  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
```

Comment: Any recent change of your JDK ?

Comment: @nquincampoix No, there is no JDK change. It is not consistent as well. After cleaning the target directory(maven clean build), sometimes it goes away.

Comment: It got resolved after I changed the setting in Intellij to pick processors path to pick from project rather than from processor path.

Comment: Glad you found out (I was out of clues). You should explain it as an answer to yourself, in case someone else encounters this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I got the issue solved when I changed from 1 to 2 (see attached screenshot), then Build>Rebuild project.